# How to check if the system has AMD or NVIDIA in C#?

Tags: c#, cuda, opencl, ethereum, mining

I'm trying to make an Ethereum mining client using C#, and I need to check whether the system has AMD or NVIDIA. This is because the program needs to know whether it should mine Ethereum via CUDA or OpenCL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use System.Management Namespace (You can find under references/Assemblies)

After adding namespace you need to navigate all properties of ManagementObject and navigate all properties of propertydata till founding description on name property.

I wrote this solution for console app. You can adapt your solution.

Try this:

```
 using System;
 using System.Management;

 namespace ConsoleApp1
 {
 class Program
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new 
 ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DisplayConfiguration");

        string gc = "";
        foreach (ManagementObject obj in searcher.Get())
        {
            foreach (PropertyData prop in obj.Properties)
            {
                if (prop.Name == "Description")
                {
                    gc = prop.Value.ToString().ToUpper();

                    if (gc.Contains("INTEL") == true)
                    {
                      Console.WriteLine("Your Graphic Card is Intel");
                    }
                    else if (gc.Contains("AMD") == true)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Your Graphic Card is AMD");
                    }
                    else if (gc.Contains("NVIDIA") == true)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Your Graphic Card is NVIDIA");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Your Graphic Card cannot recognized.");

                    }
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```