# How to check whether the user is using NVIDIA or AMD in C++

Tags: windows, c++-cli

I need a way to be able to check this. I know how to do this in C#:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49349037/8978746

But how do we do this in C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use OpenGL Api's  `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` method to get the information you needed.
Here is an example usage;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 glutInit(&argc, argv); // creates opengl context
 glutInitContextVersion(4, 4); // this is the version that works for me
 glutCreateWindow("Test");
 const GLubyte *vendor = glGetString( GL_VENDOR ); // returns the Vendor of Card
 const GLubyte *version = glGetString( GL_VERSION ); // returns the version of the Card
}
```

You can read more about it [here](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context#Context_information_queries).